# URLs and other information

Tags: bibtex

I am having a problem.

My `bib` files contains:

```
@misc{hfs+,
Date-Added = {2012-10-18 15:39:01 +0100},
Date-Modified = {2012-10-18 15:44:41 +0100},
Howpublished = {\url{http://developer.apple.com/legacy/mac/library/#technotes/tn/tn1150.html}},
Institution = {Apple Computer, Inc.},
Month = {March},
Number = {Technical Note TN1150},
Title = {HFS Plus Volume Format},
Year = {2004}}
```

and the displayed reference in my bibliography is:

```
Hfs plus volume format. http://developer.apple.com/legacy/mac/library/#technotes/tn/tn1150.html, March 2004.
```

How can I get something like:

```
Hfs plus volume format. Technical Note TN1150, http://developer.apple.com/legacy/mac/library/#technotes/tn/tn1150.html, 
March 2004, Apple Computer, Inc., Last checked 2012-10-18 15:44.
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Which bibliography style file do you use? Please advise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The appearance of typeset bibliographic entries is determined by the bibliography style file you use. You don't state which style file you use, forcing me to assume that you use a fairly generic style such as `plainnat`. I'll also assume you're using the `natbib` citation management package.

A minimum working example (MWE) might look like this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\bibliographystyle{plainnat}
\usepackage{url,natbib}
\begin{document}
\nocite{*}
\bibliography{bibbib}
\end{document}
```

and a sample `.bib` file -- called "bibbib.bib", say -- that works with the `plainnat` bibliography style would look like:

```
@misc{hfs+,
  Date-Added = {2012-10-18 15:39:01 +0100},
  note = {Apple Computer, Inc., Last checked 2012-10-18 15:44:41 +0100},
  howpublished = {\url{http://developer.apple.com/legacy/mac/library/#technotes/tn/tn1150.html}},
  Month = {March},
  Title = {{HFS Plus Volume Format. Technical Note TN1150}},
  Year = {2004}
}
```

Running latex, bibtex, and latex twice more generates this:

[image]

Comment: I noticed that too. I just refactored it and placed Apple Computer Inc. as the author.

Comment: Indeed, it's better in this case to have an `author` field.